# click function, to fire only once then never again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a deal or no deal game, where the first time the users loads the page they have to click a box to select it as theirs. After that they then progress through clicking the various boxes.

However, I don't know how to make my function for selecting the box only run the 1 click!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function noop() {};

    function chooseBox() {

        $(".box").on( "click", function( event ) {
            $boxID = $(this).attr('id');
            $boxValue = $(this).attr('rel');
            $boxNumber = $boxID.replace('box','');
            $usersBox = $("#users-box span");

            $usersBox.html($boxNumber);
            $usersBox.attr('rel', $boxValue);
            $usersBox.addClass('chosen');

            chooseBox = noop;
        });
    }

    chooseBox();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="boxes">
    <ul class="box-choices">
        <li id="box1" class="box" rel="30.00"><span>1</span></li>
        <li id="box2" class="box" rel="25.00"><span>2</span></li>
        <li id="box3" class="box" rel="5.00"><span>3</span></li>
        <li id="box4" class="box" rel="2.50"><span>4</span></li>
        <li id="box5" class="box" rel="225.00"><span>5</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="box-choices">
        <li id="box6" class="box" rel="75.00"><span>6</span></li>
        <li id="box7" class="box" rel="15.00"><span>7</span></li>
        <li id="box8" class="box" rel="10.00"><span>8</span></li>
        <li id="box9" class="box" rel="7.50"><span>9</span></li>
        <li id="box10" class="box" rel="0.01"><span>10</span></li>
        <li id="box11" class="box" rel="300.00"><span>11</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="box-choices">
        <li id="box12" class="box" rel="100.00"><span>12</span></li>
        <li id="box13" class="box" rel="50.00"><span>13</span></li>
        <li id="box14" class="box" rel="0.50"><span>14</span></li>
        <li id="box15" class="box" rel="1.00"><span>15</span></li>
        <li id="box16" class="box" rel="275.00"><span>16</span></li>
        <li id="box17" class="box" rel="200.00"><span>17</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="box-choices">
        <li id="box18" class="box" rel="150.00"><span>18</span></li>
        <li id="box19" class="box" rel="125.00"><span>19</span></li>
        <li id="box20" class="box" rel="250.00"><span>20</span></li>
        <li id="box21" class="box" rel="175.00"><span>21</span></li>
        <li id="box22" class="box" rel="20.00"><span>22</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/), but if you intend to use the .box calls for all boxes maybe separate initial box selection from game boxes by being more specific `$(".box-choice .box")`

Comment: I will be using .box calls for all, is there anyway to not have to remove initial box selection from the same game boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the only way to target the same boxes would be to use all the code in 1 function with a counter to execute the code:

```
var countBoxes = 0;

    function playingGame() {
        $(".box").on( "click", function( event ) {

            if(countBoxes < 1) {
                $boxID = $(this).attr('id');
                $boxValue = $(this).attr('rel');
                $boxNumber = $boxID.replace('box','');
                $usersBox = $("#users-box span");

                $usersBox.html($boxNumber);
                $usersBox.attr('rel', $boxValue);
                $usersBox.addClass('chosen');

                $(this).addClass('live-chosen');

                countBoxes = 1;
            } else {
```

Comment: if you have more than one box, this will make the rest not work. I assume you only want to disable the click handler for the current box that is clicked

Comment: This solution works as expected. After 1 click it increases the count so the function no longer runs for selecting the first box whereas everything after works as it's 1 or greater than.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the disabled attribute to the button that was clicked. so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

function noop() {};

function chooseBox() {

    $(".box").on( "click", function( event ) {
        $boxID = $(this).attr('id');
        $boxValue = $(this).attr('rel');
        $boxNumber = $boxID.replace('box','');
        $usersBox = $("#users-box span");

        $usersBox.html($boxNumber);
        $usersBox.attr('rel', $boxValue);
        $usersBox.addClass('chosen');

        event.currentTarget.attr('disabled',true)
    });
}

  chooseBox();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery's `one` event binding if you only need the button to fire the click event once.

See the snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

function noop() {};

function chooseBox() {

    $(".box").one( "click", function( event ) {
        console.log('I am clicked once');
    });
}

  chooseBox();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='box'>111</button>
<button class='box'>222</button>
<button class='box'>333</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work as they're all called box and need to be interacted with cosntantly